# Java calcular descuento para agencia de viajes

Tags: java, condiciones

Una agencia de viajes encargada de distribuir tiquetes de avión, realiza las siguientes
actividades al vender un tiquete:

a. Calcula el costo del mismo conociendo el recorrido en kilómetros y el valor decada kilómetro.

b. Al costo calculado le hace un descuento del 6%

c. Al costo después de descuento le aplica un IVA del 19%

d. Al costo después del IVA le saca el 8% para el vendedor

e. Al costo después del IVA le saca el 5% para la agencia

f. Lo que queda después de los descuentos es para la aerolínea y el IVA

Realice los diversos cálculos requeridos utilizando métodos independientes para cada
cálculo, finalmente suponga que vendió 3 tiquetes y muestre el total que cada usuario
pago por el tiquete y ¿cuánto recibió en total, cada una de las partes (IVA, vendedor,
agencia y aerolínea) involucradas?

tengo algo que he intentado pero no me funciona me pueden ayudar gracias

```
public Venta(int valor, int dis) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int dis,valor, vkm ; 
        double valIva, valAg, valAer , precVent, valDesc, aerolinea, iva;

        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
        // se crea un objeto en la clase

        System.out.println ("Digite la cantidad de kilometros ");
        dis=Integer.parseInt(leer.nextLine()); //leer cantidad de km

        System.out.println("Digite el precio por kilometros"); //ingresar el precio por km
        valor= Integer.parseInt(leer.nextLine());  //leer el preccio por Km
        Venta obj1 = new Venta(vkm,dis); // creamos un objeto de la clase tiquetes y le damos parametros al constructor



        valDesc=obj1.valor*0.94;
        valIva=obj1.valor*1.19;
        precVent=obj1.valIva*0.08;
        valAg=obj1.valIva*0.05;
        aerolinea=obj1.valor- valAer-precVent;
        iva=obj1.aerolinea*0.19;

        System.out.println("El costo del valor con iva es..."+ valIva);
        System.out.println("La agencia gana..."+ valAg);
        system.out.println("la aerolinea gana"+ valAer);
        System.out.println("El vendedor gano"+precVent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Muestra la clase `venta`, además veo algunos cálculos mal.

Comment: Que  quiere decir no me funciona? que cosa no funciona? podes aclarar la pregunta?

Comment: Ayuda me no me funciona nada ayuda me porfa

Comment: Hola recuerda que de preferencia debes especificar de preferencia en que punto no funciona, que dificultades tienes, revisa [ask] ,saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Los datos los pides en Enteros no se porque los capturas en String y lo conviertes a Enteros. Ademas le estas ya pasando el dis y valor, no entiendo mucho lo que quieres hacer. Pasa las demas clases a ver.

`dis=Integer.parseInt(leer.nextLine()); // esto sería dis = leer.nextInt();
valor= Integer.parseInt(leer.nextLine()); // esto sería valor = leer.nextInt();`

No se como ayudarte mas porque no tengo las otras clases ademas tienes algunos calculos mas. Tambien pasa el error que te da en consola.